# It sounds all good until

Tags: lateral-thinking

If

**4 + 4 = 8**

**10 - 5 = 5**

**5 x 1 = 5**

**8 - 1 = 7**

**2 + 4 = 7**

Then,

**8 / 1 = ?**

**Is it 6 or 7 ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4 + 4 = 8

> IV + IV = 8 strokes to write out (for example, the + sign is 2 strokes)

10 - 5 = 5

> X - V = 5 strokes

5 x 1 = 5

> V x I = 5

8 - 1 = 7

> VIII - I = 7

2 + 4 = 7

> II + IV = 7

So....

> VIII / I = 7 strokes to write out

Comment: Way to figure it out @Amoz!